Rails - Foreign Key Constraint Failure For Belongs To-Has Many Relationship
class Appointment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :teacher
  belongs_to :student
end

class Teacher < User
    has_many :appointments
end

class Student < User
    has_many :appointments
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
    has_secure_password

    validates :username, presence: true
    validates :username, uniqueness: true
    validates :username, length: { minimum: 4 }
    validates :email, presence: true
    validates :email, uniqueness: true
end

Schema:
ActiveRecord::Schema[7.0].define(version: 2024_06_06_180259) do
  create_table "appointments", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "start_datetime"
    t.integer "teacher_id", null: false
    t.integer "student_id", null: false
    t.string "notes"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "status"
    t.index ["teacher_id"], name: "index_appointments_on_teacher_id"
    t.index ["student_id"], name: "index_appointments_on_student_id"
  end

  create_table "teachers", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "students", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "email"
    t.string "username"
    t.string "password_digest"
    t.string "first_name"
    t.string "last_name"
    t.string "type"
    t.string "phone_number"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  add_foreign_key "appointments", "teachers"
  add_foreign_key "appointments", "students"
end

I was previously having problems with using STI to represent Teachers and Students in the same Users db table. But now I've made separate tables for Teachers and Students. Still, I'm getting the foreign key constraint failed error. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. It looks like I did my associations correctly. Can someone guide me here?

you say Coaches, i see Teachers. you're still using STI by inheriting from User.

belongs_to :coach -> belongs_to :teacher

@Alex Is this a Rails feature or do subclasses generally live in the same db as their parent class?

when you inherit from another model, all the STI behavior kicks in, and subclasses use their parent's table. https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ModelSchema/ClassMethods.html#method-i-table_name

I think this may have been an issue with SQLite, but I will need to confirm first on MySQL/Postgres. For now, the fix was re-running the migration to create the appointments table using the below migration code that was able to successfully create the association between appointments and students & teachers. The important change is adding to the references foreign_key: { to_table: :users } to formally link the users table. Up until this point, no other suggestion was working but this fixed the issue. I will update when I have time to check against MySQL.
class CreateAppointments < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
  def change
    create_table :appointments do |t|
      t.datetime :start_datetime
      t.references :teacher, null: false, foreign_key: { to_table: :users }
      t.references :student, null: true, foreign_key: { to_table: :users }
      t.string :status

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end



You can separate the teachers and students into separate models with the same backing users table. This is a common pattern. Although, I would only do that if there is logical difference between teachers and students (not currently demonstrated in your example).
If you do this, you do NOT need to create a teachers table nor a students table in your database. It's better if you don't.
Rails assumes when you use belongs_to that the identifier is the table name, but you can override this.
class Appointment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :teacher, class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :student, class_name: "User"
end

The above would tell Rails to look for the teacher_id and student_id on the users.id column and should solve your foreign key constraint problem.

This unfortunately does not work, I am getting the following: SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: main.students (ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid)

It would be helpful if you would add the code that is generating this error.

It is still the original code above, with your changes, specifically class_name: "User" added in. For some reason it didn't work here, but adding the equivalent in the migration file when creating the appointments table and re-doing the migration worked. I'm not sure why your suggestion did not have the same effect.
